# Why Trigger collection doesnt allow Data Triggers

Tags: wpf, triggers

Why Trigger collection doesnt allow the Data Triggers and other Triggers except the Event trigger?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Name="LblHeader"
                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           Content="Test"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="SteelBlue" />
    <Button Name="BtnAttach" Content="_Attach"/>

    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel }}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="LblHeader" Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers can be specified at four levels....

1. At `ControlTemplate` Level
2. At `DataTemplate` level
3. At `Style` Level
4. `UIElement` Level.

`DataTrigger` work only at first three levels. Ideally it should be used only in second case i.e. `Style` or `DataTemplate`.

But first can your clarify what is your intention with this code?

Do you want to show `Label` text as `Gray` when StackPanel is disabled?

If so `IsEnabled` property is a inheritable dependency property which means it will be applied to all elements under the visual tree of the parent which is disabled.

So if `StackPanel` gets disabled so will be the `Label` under it.

In that case a `PropertyTrigger` is sufficient as below...

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Name="LblHeader"
           Margin="10,0,10,0"
           Content="Test"
           FontWeight="Bold">
      <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label"> 
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue" />
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Label.Style>
    </Label>  
    <Button Name="BtnAttach" Content="_Attach"/>        
</StackPanel>
```